# How do I combine stdout and stderr for different shells?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I know the answer for some shells, e.g. with `cmd.exe` you can:

```
some.exe > out.txt 2>&1
```

How do you achieve the same for other shells (bash, ksh, tcsh, powershell, etc)?

Answer (score 18):

**Fish shell**

To redirect both standard output and standard error to the file all_output.txt, you can write:

```
echo Hello > all_output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: if piping output to next command, use 2>| instead: echo Hello 2>| less

Comment: The piping syntax may have changed. My fish shell uses the same syntax "^&1" for both.

Comment: `2>&1` also works — `^` is essentially fish's shorthand for `>2`.  Note that `2>| less` or `^| less` by itself pipes *only* stderr; to pipe both our and err, do `^&1 | less`

Comment: Syntax shorthands for redirecting/piping both out and err are still under discussion https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/110

Comment: The `^` operator was deprecated in fish 3.0 (2018-12-28) and disabled by default in fish 3.3 (2021-06-28). Don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

For csh and tcsh

```
some.exec >& out.txt
```

Comment: for tcsh, you also have `some.exec |& less`

Answer (score 3):

In [Powershell](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html) it is exactly the same:

```
2>&1      Sends errors to the        get-process none, powershell 2>&1
          success output stream.
```

(from `about_Redirection`).

In [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) and ksh at least I also know it works this way.

It seems to be a common convention.

A quick way to find out about it is by opening the man page of the shell and do a search for `&1` (with `/` and then typing `&1`). This rarely occurs in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you do exactly the same.

```
./some_exec > out 2>&1
```